# Redux dispatch making screen render and causing warning after Wix Navigation.push() is called

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm fetching some data from backend, working around with the messages array obtained, and setting it through Redux, synchronously, I execute Navigation.push(). Noticed that since render is being called due to the Redux call, it's throwing a warning on console about the state change on unmount component because it's already rendering the new screen when that happens.

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
```

This is my function where the magic begins (?

```
_getGroupMessages(groupData) {
        this._chatClient.getMessages({chatGroupId: groupData.key, limit: this.limit, offset: this.offset })
        .then(msgs => {
            let {userInfo} = this.props;

            // set new offset to retrieve more messages later if any
            this.offset = this.offset + msgs.length;

            let messages = this._handleRetrievedGroupMessages(msgs, groupData);
            this.props.onAddChatMessage(messages, true);

            Navigation.push(this.props.componentId, {
                component: {
                    name: 'myapp.ChatScreen',
                    passProps: {
                        onRefreshReadByGroup: this._onRefreshReadByGroupId,
                        onHandleTyping: this._onHandleTyping,
                        isTargetTyping: this.state.isTargetTyping,
                        reloadMoreMessages: this._getMoreGroupMessages,
                        userId: userInfo.id,
                        name: userInfo.fullName || userInfo.name,
                        chatData: groupData
                    },
                    options: {
                        animated: true,
                        bottomTabs: {
                            visible: false,
                            drawBehind: true,
                            animate: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

I'm not doing any setState in those functions, the only thing executing is the userReducer to set the redux messages state when I call `this.props.onAddChatMessage(messages, true);`

I know it's this because i commented out the entire `Navigation.push` call and the warning is not thrown of course, because the screen isn't unmounting.

I attempted to put the `Navigation.push` within a setTimeout of 2s and it worked. But that is super dirty.

How can I make this work?

It's a chat list group, that whenever I tap on a group, it takes me to the actual chat. Hence, I need to retrieve the group messages by key and take the user to the chat screen.

Any help is appreciated. (I'd prefer not implementing the `this._isMounted` workaround since it's also very dirty)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're missing a setState call somewhere, redux updates alone do not call setState and cannot trigger this warning.

Comment: Yea, it's driving me crazy. I put a breakpoint on every setState i have in that class, and none is triggering whenever i tap on the chat group.

Comment: Is there a way to know what's is calling a re-render ???

Comment: Ahhhh, the problem might be the function shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
        return (
            !_.isEqual(nextProps, this.props) || !_.isEqual(nextState, this.state)
        );
    }
since this is a chat with sockets, props and states are currently changing so it triggers a re-render.... damn :(

Comment: Could it be possible that the set state is happening in some other component that is being unmounted when the push happens? Based on the fact that you're passing `this._onHandleTyping` in the push call I'm wondering if the parent component here is even getting unmounted at all? If it is then that callback would stop working so wouldn't make sense to pass it.

Comment: Im thinking it could be the darn gifted-chat. I will check on that. onHandleTyping is only executed when you start typing on the ChatScreen. I already checked, is not called on ChatScreen.mount(). It seems that it might be called in gifted-chat or something.